How to Fine-Tune mBART or mT5 for Transliteration from Romanized Text to Native Script?
I'm working on a project that involves converting Romanized text (where the characters are in the Latin alphabet) into its corresponding native script. Specifically, I'm dealing with Romanized Hindi (e.g., "aap kaise hain?") and need to convert it into native Hindi script ("आप कैसे हैं?").
Both the mBART and mT5 models, which are trained on Hindi among other languages, seem like good candidates for this task, but I'm unsure of the best approach to fine-tune these models for transliteration.
Here’s what I’m working with:

Data: I have a parallel dataset where each Romanized sentence is paired with its corresponding native script sentence.
Models: I'm considering mBART and mT5, as they both support Hindi, which is crucial for my task.

I need help with the following:

Data Preparation:


How should I format my dataset for fine-tuning? Should I treat this as a translation task where the input is Romanized text, and the output is the native script?


Model Fine-Tuning:


What steps should I follow to fine-tune mBART or mT5 for this specific transliteration task?
Are there specific hyperparameters or training settings that work well for transliteration?


For the first question if I understand correctly, you are trying to perform Transliteration and the translation approach is interesting and might work.
For the second question, Here is how you might do it using transformers from huggingface, Assuming you have some computational resources (GPU) which you can get from colab or paperspace.
Import libs
import tensorflow as tf
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import TFMT5ForConditionalGeneration, MT5Tokenizer, DataCollatorForSeq2Seq
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

Load your model and tokenizer
tokenizer = MT5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("google/mt5-small")
model = TFMT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/mt5-small")

Load your data and prepare it for training
dataset = load_dataset("csv", data_files="your-path-to-dataset.csv")

Data preparation before feeding to model
dataset = dataset["train"].shuffle(seed=42)
def preprocess_function(examples):
    padding = "max_length"
    max_length = 126

    inputs = [ex for ex in examples["input"]] # Latin 
    targets = [ex for ex in examples["output"]] # Hindi
    model_inputs = tokenizer(inputs, max_length=max_length, padding=padding, truncation=True)
    labels = tokenizer(targets, max_length=max_length, padding=padding, truncation=True)

    model_inputs["labels"] = labels["input_ids"]
    return model_inputs
train_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True, desc="Running tokenizer")

The above steps shuffle your dataset and tokenize it. Use the following lines to set batch size and padding to your dataset.
data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(
    tokenizer,
    model=model,
    label_pad_token_id=tokenizer.pad_token_id,
    pad_to_multiple_of=64,
    return_tensors="np")

tf_train_dataset = model.prepare_tf_dataset(
    train_dataset,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=8,
    shuffle=True)

After that you can start fine-tuning your mode.
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(3e-5))
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3)
model.fit(tf_train_dataset, epochs=10, callbacks=[early_stopping])

Here we are setting the learning rate to 3e-5, that seem to be good place to start, of course you can make this value change while the training progress check out keras for more info, check your loss, accuracy and do validation. In general you have to experiment with this values start with maybe with small model, and small epochs and see if it can generalize and change the hyperparameters to improve performance.
(*edit), you might not need LLMs for this task, you can try simpler RNN networks.
